# getElementById doesn't get the correct element?

Tags: javascript, dom, anime.js

I need to get a dom node using getElementById to do animations on it. The element is in a div with other sibling elements with similar properties. However, getElementById is getting a different element than specified?

```
const target = document.getElementById(notification._id);
console.log(notification._id);
console.log(target);
//animations
anime({
    targets: target,
    opacity: [1,0],
    duration: 500,
});
```

[image]

I cannot figure out for the life of me why its getting a sibling element with a different Id?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your element ID is one being automatically generated. Since you're using this to select an element that is being animated, is it possible that the element changes IDs (by animating to the next frame) midway through your selection process?

Comment: Thought about the same. Maybe some process is incrementing ids on the elements, wanted or unwanted. So it selects the correct one but when we log out the target, 1 has already been added to the element id. `document.getElementById` is reliable, I strongly doubt that it makes an error and returns a wrong element.

Comment: I don't think the ids are being changed in any way, the end result id after the incorrect animation is still the same as the one in the database.